# Const with smart pointers in C++

Tags: c++, constants, smart-pointers, copy-constructor

I'm writing a smart pointer implementation in C++, and I'm having some trouble with const-correctness. Below is an excerpt from the code:

```
template <class T> class Pointer {
  T* pointee;

public:  

  Pointer(const Pointer<T>& other) { // must be const Pointer& for assignments
    pointee = other.getPointee();
  }

  T* getPointee() const {
    return pointee;
  }
};
```

This is one way to do it, however I feel uneasy the `const` member not returning a `const` pointer. Another possibility would be to let `getPointee()` return a `const T*` and perform a `const_cast<T*>` in the copy constructor.

Is there a better way of doing this? If not, which do you think to be the lesser evil, returning a non-const or doing a `const_cast`?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are trying to write your own smart pointer.  Most of the time, the ones provided by the standard do a fine job.

Comment: Yes, there is. I'm using internal reference counting in my objects.

Comment: Boost provides an intrusive smart pointer: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint, although I probably can't use it, it's always nice to see how Boost solved it ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best to think of your constant smart pointer as a constant pointer to a non-constant object. This is similar to:

```
int * const int_ptr;
```

If you wanted a pointer to a constant object:

```
Pointer<const int> const_int_smart_ptr;
```

which is basically equivalent to:

```
const int *const_int_ptr;
```

Comment: so you would choose the version i wrote in the question?

Comment: yes - the constant pointer can't be made to point to something different, (e.g. operator= should not be allowed for const Pointer), but the value of whatever it points to should be changeable.

Answer (score 4):

The object designated by `pointee` doesn't seem to belong to `Pointer`,
so I see no reason to assume that calling a `const` function of
`Pointer` would return a `T const*`, rather than a `T*`.  (If the
pointed to object were conceptually part of `Pointer`, of course, the
issue would be different.)

Comment: "_If the pointed to object were conceptually part of Pointer_" then the class is no longer a "pointer", rather a container.